# Inverting the ST_Within query

Tags: sql, postgis

I'm using ST_Within, which works fine, but I want to select all points which are not within the convex hull, how do I invert the selection in sql?

```
SELECT geom FROM pc_processing.pc_201406151141_top top

WHERE st_within(top.geom, (
SELECT st_convexhull(st_collect(geom)) as geom
FROM pc_processing.pc_201407060711_base))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`ST_Within`](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Within.html) returns a boolean, so you can check that the result is `false`

```
SELECT geom FROM pc_processing.pc_201406151141_top top
WHERE st_within(top.geom, 
           (SELECT st_convexhull(st_collect(geom)) as geom
            FROM pc_processing.pc_201407060711_base
            )
      ) = false;
```